# NullPointerException while getting data from DB, using annotation to call Action in Struts 2

Tags: java, struts2, annotations

**EDIT**

This is my Action Class

```java
public class StatusAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<Status>{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5686197289029560661L;

    private Status status = new Status();
    private List<Status> lstStatus = new ArrayList<Status>();
    private StatusService sttService = new StatusServiceImpl();

    @Override
    public Status getModel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return status;
    }

    @Action(value="/lstStatus", results={
            @Result(name="success", location="/list.jsp")
    })
    public String list(){
        lstStatus = sttService.listStatus();
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    @Action(value="/hello", results={
            @Result(name="success", location="/NewFile.jsp")
    })
    public String hello1(){
        return SUCCESS;
    }


    //get, set
    public Status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Status status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public List<Status> getLstStatus() {
        return lstStatus;
    }

    public void setLstStatus(List<Status> lstStatus) {
        this.lstStatus = lstStatus;
    }
}
```

When I use Action annotation instead of xml, it throws `NullPointerException`. But when I use xml, it run without exception.

My `struts.xml`:

```xml
   <action name="lstStatus" method="list" class="com.sem4.actions.StatusAction">
        <result name="success">/list.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

Here is exception:

```
   Server startup in 3621 ms
   java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sem4.dao.StatusDAOImpl.getListStatus(StatusDAOImpl.java:25)
at com.sem4.service.StatusServiceImpl.listStatus(StatusServiceImpl.java:16)
at com.sem4.actions.StatusAction.list(StatusAction.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:440)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:279)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:163)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:249)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:148)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:93)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:128)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:104)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:148)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:128)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:468)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is StatusDAOImpl (implement StatusDAO interface)

```
   @SessionTarget
Session ss;
@TransactionTarget
Transaction tran;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<Status> getListStatus() {
    List<Status> lst = new ArrayList<Status>();
    try{
        lst = ss.createQuery("from Status")
                .list();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return lst;
}
```

And this StatusServiceImpl (impl StatusService interface)

```
   private StatusDAO sttDAO = new StatusDAOImpl();

@Override
public List<Status> listStatus() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return sttDAO.getListStatus();
}
```

Note: I use annotations when I call a method with no data from DB, it's ok.

What I can do to fix that?

Comment: Post complete stacktrace of the exception

Comment: Thank for your reply! I edited with full exception. Pls help!

Comment: show the `struts.xml` file related to this configuration. Are you extending any packages? Is SessionTarget is related to hibernate?

Comment: I don't have struts.xml because I used annotation and it configed in web.xml. When I create struts.xml for mapping action (remove annotation), it's ok, without exception. Only when I use annotation to call action --> throw that Exception. SessionTarget related to hibernate, sure, if not it won't run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the exception stacktrace it is clear that the `Session ss` is `null`. So Struts is not injecting the dependencies for you as you are trying to add the `package hibernate-default` for the action class. Because this package has the interceptor called `basicStackHibernate` which will help to inject the required dependencies.

To fix the issue, add below annotations to your action class:

```
@ParentPackage("hibernate-default")
@InterceptorRef("basicStackHibernate")
public class StatusAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<Status>{}
```

Refer to this similar post for more details:

[Struts + Hibernate: @SessionTarget not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22549634/struts-hibernate-sessiontarget-not-working)