# HIbernate struts2 session exception

Tags: java, hibernate, session, struts2

I am creating one simple login example using struts2 and hibernate. For doing this I am creating one session variable with @SessionTarget annotation. But when I am trying to use this session variable then I am getting null pointer exception.

```
            @SessionTarget
            Session session;

            public void userLogin(String userName, String password) {
                  try {
                  String hql = "select user_privilege from user_details log where log.userName=:userName and log.password=:passw";
                  Query query = session.createQuery(hql); // From here I am getting exception
                  query.setParameter("userName", userName);
                  query.setParameter("password", passw);
                  List result = query.list();
                  Iterator iterator = result.iterator();
                  while(iterator.hasNext()){
                    userId = (int) iterator.next();
                  }
                } catch (HibernateException e) {
                } finally {
                  //session.close();
                }                   
            }
```

struts.xml

```
<package name="default" extends="hibernate-default">


        <action name="fillvacancy" method="execute" class="com.templateproject.action.FillVacancyAction">
            <result name="success">/vacancy/fillvacancy.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/vacancy/userhome.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
```

I have already asked this question before. And found one answer from this link [Struts + Hibernate: @SessionTarget not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22549634/struts-hibernate-sessiontarget-not-working).

But this solution not solved my problem.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: what server are you using ??

Comment: @goodyzain I am using tomcat server

Comment: @AleksandrM Added struts.xml file

Comment: In the previous [question of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32570173/1700321) you've said that linked post solved you problem. So what is changed?

Comment: I have only changed the action name and class name.

Comment: Is session variable created only once?

Comment: Suppose if I want to use session in another class so Can I create session variable again or can I access the old session variable?

Comment: What do you mean by create? You're injecting it.

Comment: @AleksandrM Yes. Injecting it.

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty in tomcat you cant inject session,you need to have JEE server which is Jboss,Tomee,Websphere etc..

Comment: @goodyzain How can I access session in tomcat server?

Comment: @goodyzai Of course you can. With a plugin.

Comment: @AleksandrM How to do that? Can you give some example? so that I can implement it in my project.

Comment: You are already using a plugin. Where, do you think, `@SessionTarget` comes from?

Comment: I have use it but I got null pointer exception.